# how to view registration form data after clicking signup button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

hii guys i have a code that consists of login and registration forms as a tabs when we clicked on either ones it goes on to that respective form but now I want to change it a bit by removing the Register tab and adding it as a signup button beside login button and in the register page i want to add login button when i click it its goes to login form vice-versa..

PS:- I am new to HTML and Bootstrap and i want this to be done in pure HTML r Bootstrap

here is the code of signup.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#login-form" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#register-form" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <form id="login-form" class="tab-pane  show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab" action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                    <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row logs">
                      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google" (click)="signInGoogle()" >Login with Google</button>
                      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" (click)="signInFacebook()" >Login with Facebook</button>
                      <button class="loginBtn btn-linkedin" (click)="signInLinkedin()">
                        <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                        <span class="linkedtext">Login with LinkedIn</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <form id="register-form" class=" fade tab-pane " action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried many ways to do it but I couldn't come up.. if there is anyother way to do it please let me know thanks.

Comment: is there anyone could do it?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery makes this really easy to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#register-form').hide()
  $('#register-tab').click(function () {
   $("#login-form").hide();
    $("#register-form").show();
  })
  
  $('#login-tab').click(function () {
  $("#register-form").hide();
    $("#login-form").show();
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#login-form" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#register-form" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <form id="login-form" class="tab-pane  show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab" action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                    <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row logs">
                      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google" (click)="signInGoogle()" >Login with Google</button>
                      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" (click)="signInFacebook()" >Login with Facebook</button>
                      <button class="loginBtn btn-linkedin" (click)="signInLinkedin()">
                        <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                        <span class="linkedtext">Login with LinkedIn</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <form id="register-form" class=" fade tab-pane " action="#" method="post" role="form" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want it to be in pure html n bootstrap can it be done by using that?

Comment: Don't think thats possible with html and css. Javascript (or jquery) adds interaction on your webpage. So this is actually a really easy task to do with either js or jquery

Comment: But you could have a look at this example: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel

Comment: actually i am using this as a angular components so i cannot add jquery r js code to my project

Comment: Angular is just a javascript framework. So its possible to use Jquery. There is lots of content out there on how to implement jquery within angular.

Comment: Looking at your question history it seems someone already answered this quiestion with the same arguments. It will be really hard to do this without javascript.